# Gratest common divisor problem

Tags: number-theory

Let $a_1, a_2,...,a_n \in\mathbb Z$ not all equal to zero prove that:

$gcd(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=gcd(a_1,gcd(a_2,...,a_n)$

I tried using induction but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391)

Comment: This has been asked here before, most likely.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to prouve this in two parts.
First, prove that:
$$ gcd(a_1, a_2, …,a_n) | gcd(a_1, gcd(a_2, a_3,…, a_n)) $$
Then prove that:
$$ gcd(a_1, gcd(a_2, a_3, …, a_n)) | gcd(a_1, a_2, …, a_n) $$

It must be good, you can try with $n=3$ to notice a pattern.